# object Object issue using append

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, append

My goal is to create a to-do list and having the possibility to add more items to the list.

I'm using the `.append()` method to add content. However, I also need to add a checkbox for every new item added.

Here's what I have so far

(Run the code snippet and add a new item, you'll see the error I'm having)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 $("#button").click(function() {
  var check = $("<input>", { type: "checkbox" });
  var toAdd = $("input[name=ListItem]").val();
  $("ul").append($("<li>" + check + "<label>" + toAdd + "</label>" + "</li>"));
 });
});
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Josefin+Sans');
ul {
 list-style: none;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}
li {
 margin: 50px 0;
 font-family: 'Josefin Sans', sans-serif;
 font-size: 20px;
 font-weight: bolder;
}
input {
 cursor: pointer;
 position: relative;
 visibility: hidden;
}
input:after {
 border: 3px solid lightblue;
 border-radius: 50%;;
 content: "";
 display: block;
 height: 46px;
 width: 46px;
 text-align: center;
 visibility: visible;
 transition: all 100ms ease-in-out;
}
input:checked:after {
 border: 3px solid lightblue;
 color: white;
 font-size: 30px;
 border-radius: 50%;
 content: "✘";
 line-height: 43px;
 background-color: lightblue;
 animation: bounce 300ms ease-in-out forwards;
}
@keyframes bounce {
 0% {transform: scale(1, 1);}
 70% {transform: scale(1.1, 1.1);}
 100% {transform: scale(1, 1);}
}
label {
 position: relative;
 left: 50px;
 top: 18px;!important
}
input[type=text] {
 border: 3px solid lightblue;
 width: 100px;
 height: 50px;
 visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="list">
 <h1>To do list</h1>
 <form name="toDoList">
  <input type="text" name="ListItem" />
 </form>
 <div id="button">Add</div>
 <ul>
  <li>
   <input type="checkbox">
   <label for="checkbox">Item1</label>
  </li>
  <li>
   <input type="checkbox">
   <label for="checkbox">Item2</label>
  </li>
  <li>
   <input type="checkbox">
   <label for="checkbox">Item3</label>
  </li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: var check = "<input type='checkbox'>"; , simply dont mix strings and objects

Comment: You're appending jQuery objects to a string. Either create the HTML as one big string, or append multiple objects together. You can't do both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were appending `Object` to a `string`, and hence the error. Below is the updated working version of your code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#button").click(function() {
    var toAdd = $("input[name=ListItem]").val();
    $("ul").append($("<li><input type='checkbox'><label>" + toAdd + "</label>" + "</li>"));
  });
});
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Josefin+Sans');
ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

li {
  margin: 50px 0;
  font-family: 'Josefin Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: bolder;
}

input {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
  visibility: hidden;
}

input:after {
  border: 3px solid lightblue;
  border-radius: 50%;
  ;
  content: "";
  display: block;
  height: 46px;
  width: 46px;
  text-align: center;
  visibility: visible;
  transition: all 100ms ease-in-out;
}

input:checked:after {
  border: 3px solid lightblue;
  color: white;
  font-size: 30px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  content: "✘";
  line-height: 43px;
  background-color: lightblue;
  animation: bounce 300ms ease-in-out forwards;
}

@keyframes bounce {
  0% {
    transform: scale(1, 1);
  }
  70% {
    transform: scale(1.1, 1.1);
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(1, 1);
  }
}

label {
  position: relative;
  left: 50px;
  top: 18px;
  !important
}

input[type=text] {
  border: 3px solid lightblue;
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="list">
  <h1>To do list</h1>
  <form name="toDoList">
    <input type="text" name="ListItem" />
  </form>
  <div id="button">Add</div>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <input type="checkbox">
      <label for="checkbox">Item1</label>
    </li>
    <li>
      <input type="checkbox">
      <label for="checkbox">Item2</label>
    </li>
    <li>
      <input type="checkbox">
      <label for="checkbox">Item3</label>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Keeping most of your code as it was, it is enough to fix the `.append` command, using the functions `get(0).outerHTML()` as follows:

```
$("ul").append($("<li>" + check.get(0).outerHTML() + "<label>" + toAdd + "</label>" + "</li>"));
```

The function `get(0)` selects the first (and only) element in the object and `.outerHTML()` generates HTML from the jQuery object.

Here is the working snippet:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 $("#button").click(function() {
  var check = $("<input>", { type: "checkbox" });
  var toAdd = $("input[name=ListItem]").val();
alert(check.get(0).outerHTML);
  $("ul").append($("<li>" + check.get(0).outerHTML + "<label>" + toAdd + "</label>" + "</li>"));
 });
});
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Josefin+Sans');
ul {
 list-style: none;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}
li {
 margin: 50px 0;
 font-family: 'Josefin Sans', sans-serif;
 font-size: 20px;
 font-weight: bolder;
}
input {
 cursor: pointer;
 position: relative;
 visibility: hidden;
}
input:after {
 border: 3px solid lightblue;
 border-radius: 50%;;
 content: "";
 display: block;
 height: 46px;
 width: 46px;
 text-align: center;
 visibility: visible;
 transition: all 100ms ease-in-out;
}
input:checked:after {
 border: 3px solid lightblue;
 color: white;
 font-size: 30px;
 border-radius: 50%;
 content: "✘";
 line-height: 43px;
 background-color: lightblue;
 animation: bounce 300ms ease-in-out forwards;
}
@keyframes bounce {
 0% {transform: scale(1, 1);}
 70% {transform: scale(1.1, 1.1);}
 100% {transform: scale(1, 1);}
}
label {
 position: relative;
 left: 50px;
 top: 18px;!important
}
input[type=text] {
 border: 3px solid lightblue;
 width: 100px;
 height: 50px;
 visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="list">
 <h1>To do list</h1>
 <form name="toDoList">
  <input type="text" name="ListItem" />
 </form>
 <div id="button">Add</div>
 <ul>
  <li>
   <input type="checkbox">
   <label for="checkbox">Item1</label>
  </li>
  <li>
   <input type="checkbox">
   <label for="checkbox">Item2</label>
  </li>
  <li>
   <input type="checkbox">
   <label for="checkbox">Item3</label>
  </li>
 </ul>
</div>
```